# Frobenius in tower fields - information about a non-square $\alpha^{2k} \bmod p$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, computational-mathematics, group-homomorphism

Consider 
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb F} \newcommand{\nicefrac}[2]{#1 / #2}
\F_{p^2} & \cong \nicefrac{\F_{p}[U]}{(U^2 - \alpha)} \\[4pt]
\F_{p^4} & \cong \nicefrac{\F_{p^2}[V]}{(V^2 - U)} \\[4pt]
\F_{p^8} & \cong \nicefrac{\F_{p^4}[W]}{(W^2 - V)} \\[4pt]
\F_{p^{16}} & \cong \nicefrac{\F_{p^8}[X]}{(X^2 - W)} 
\end{align}

where $\alpha$ is a non-square in $\F_p$. Then we have $U=V^2=W^4=X^8$ and $U^2=\alpha$. Consider $p\equiv 13\bmod 32$, therefore, $-1$ is a square and $\alpha\neq -1$.

The aim is to calculate the $p$-Frobenius for $V,$ $W,$ and $X$. Let's start with $X$

$\newcommand{\clamp}[1]{\left( #1 \right)} \exists k:\ p=32k+13\Rightarrow 
X^p = \clamp{X^2}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}X = W^{16k-6}X = V^{8k-3}X = U^{4k+1}VX = \alpha^{2k}UVX$

Is there anything, that could be said about $\alpha$ in that case?
On the same way, is there any information, that could be generally passed by $\alpha$ if I compute $\alpha^{4k+1}$ and $\alpha^{8k+3}$?.

Comment: Your second equation is not correct. By adjoining the square root of a non-square, you may also get, free of charge, the fourth root of that non-square. Example: adjoin the square root of $2=-1$ to $\Bbb F_3$. You get $\Bbb F_9$, which has $(1+2\sqrt2)^2=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Could you explain it more precise, please? As we see: $3\equiv 3\bmod 4$, therefore, $-1$ is a non-square. If I would like to build up a tower on $\mathbb F_3$ to reach $\mathbb F_9$ it was recommended (by William Stein on a Sagemath question) to use $\mathbb F_9\cong \mathbb F_3[X]/(X^2+1)$. Building up $\mathbb F_{3^4}\cong \mathbb F_{3^2}[Y]/(Y^2-X)$. The aim is to choose an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_{3^2}$. I didn't checked, if such polynomals are irreucible.

Comment: I let Sage check this for me, you're right: $Y^2-X$ is not irreducible. Is there any trick or way to fix this? William Stein recommended this way for the tower 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 (k=24 instead of 16)

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{q^2} = \mathbb{F}_q[x]/(x^2-\beta)$ iff $\beta$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. Lubin explained why it is hard to know a priori which $\beta$ is good.

Comment: I see, -1 is no good choice then. -1 should be any 16-th root then? Since, if we would fix the first Tower, the 2nd one is not fixed then. Do you have any recommendations? ($U^2=V^4=W^8=X^{16}$) Btw. reuns you told me quite the same before, but I guess, I didn't understood it, like your intention was.

Comment: Hm... I guess, that there is something preventing one to find such a "Y^2-X".

Comment: The prime $2$ is special in this situation. If you had been taking cube roots (at least when the cube roots of unity were already there), I think these problems wouldn’t have arisen. Maybe values of $p\equiv1\pmod4$ might not cause you problems of the sort you see with $p=3$ and $p=7$.